# Error when trying to generate simple apk on Kivy Complete VM

Tags: kivy, clang, cython, buildozer, pyjnius

- Windows 10 x64
- VirtualBox 6.1
- Kivy Complete VM 0.7

I'm trying to generate a simple apk file and it always returns errors, I've tried to delete the virtual machine and create it again, thinking it was the result of some configuration done previously by me. I'm new to programming, I don't find that same mistake on the internet and I don't know how to solve it.

The code in "/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/main.py":

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

MyApp().run()
```

The commands in "/home/kivy/Desktop/teste":

```
buildozer init
buildozer -v android debug
```

Some things that return:

```
[INFO]:    Trying first build of pyjnius to get cython files: this is expected to fail                                                                                            
[INFO]:    -> running python3 setup.py build_ext -v
Exception in thread background thread for pid 3232:                                                                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 7
1 warning
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python3.8 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius/jnius.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'jnius/jnius.c'
clang: error: no input files
error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:


[INFO]:    pyjnius first build failed (as expected)
[INFO]:    Running cython where appropriate
[INFO]:    Cythonize jnius/jnius.pyx
[INFO]:    -> running python3 -m Cython.Build.Cythonize ./jnius/jnius.pyx

[INFO]:    -> running python3 setup.py build_ext -v                                                                                                                               
           working: error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1            Exception in thread background thread for pid 3263:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kivy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 7
1 warning
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python3.8 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:3738:89: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'JNIEnv **'
      (aka 'const struct JNINativeInterface_ ***') to parameter of type
      'void **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  ...(&__pyx_v_env), NULL));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:10723:19: warning: assigning to 'jchar *' (aka 'unsigned short *')
      from 'const jchar *' (aka 'const unsigned short *') discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  ...= (__pyx_v_j_env[0])->GetStringChars(__pyx_v_j_env, __pyx_v_j_string, NULL);
     ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:20421:30: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to
      'jobject' (aka 'struct _jobject *') from 'jobject *' (aka
      'struct _jobject **'); dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          (__pyx_v_jargs[0]) = ((jobject *)__pyx_v_classLoader);
                             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               *(                              )
jnius/jnius.c:20430:30: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to
      'jobject' (aka 'struct _jobject *') from 'jclass *' (aka
      'struct _jobject **'); dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
          (__pyx_v_jargs[1]) = __pyx_v_interfaces;
                             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                               *
jnius/jnius.c:35645:36: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  (__pyx_v_invoke_methods[0]).name = ((char const *)"invoke0");
                                   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:35654:41: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  ...= ((char const *)"(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
     ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:51997:258: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(0, 0, 0, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_env_pxi, __pyx_n_s_detach, 23, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52009:261: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__62, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_func_pxi, __pyx_n_s_cast, 4, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52021:272: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 6, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__64, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_func_pxi, __pyx_n_s_find_javaclass, 17, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52033:263: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(5, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__66, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 11, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52048:273: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 12, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__69, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_instancecheck, 43, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52060:263: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(4, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__71, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_new, 113, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52072:273: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 8, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__73, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_subclasscheck, 119, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52084:273: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(1, 0, 1, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__75, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_get_javaclass, 148, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52096:274: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 21, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__77, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_resolve_class, 152, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52108:280: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS|CO_VARKEYWORDS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__79, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 1051, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52120:280: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS|CO_VARKEYWORDS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__81, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_export_class_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 1057, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52140:255: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__84, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_proxy_pxi, __pyx_n_s_init, 2, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52155:256: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 3, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__87, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_proxy_pxi, __pyx_n_s_get_2, 7, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52167:256: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(2, 0, 2, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__89, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_jnius_jnius_proxy_pxi, __pyx_n_s_call, 10, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:52232:259: error: too many arguments to function call, expected
      15, have 16
  ...__Pyx_PyCode_New(3, 0, 5, 0, CO_OPTIMIZED|CO_NEWLOCALS, __pyx_empty_bytes, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_tuple__96, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_empty_tuple, __pyx_kp_s_stringsource, __pyx_n_s_pyx_unpickle_Enum, 1, __pyx_empty_bytes)...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:57497:9: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15,
      have 16
        __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note: 
      'PyCode_New' declared here
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
           ^
6 warnings and 16 errors generated.
error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:

                                                                                                                                                                                  
[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 213):
    jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'  
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)   
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~    
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note:   
      'PyCode_New' declared here    
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(  
           ^    
jnius/jnius.c:57497:9: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 15, 
      have 16   
        __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/ 
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
jnius/jnius.c:331:82: note: expanded from macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'  
  ...PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)   
     ~~~~~~~~~~                                                             ^~~~    
/home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/code.h:122:12: note:   
      'PyCode_New' declared here    
PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(  
           ^    
6 warnings and 16 errors generated. 
error: command '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius && /home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/kivy/Desktop/teste/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Problem solved with [another VM](https://github.com/ntaraujo/kivy-easier)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I use docker i got same error log !

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Settings:

- Virtual Environment with python=3.6.3
- Kivy=1.11.1
- Setup buildozer from master (b566125f71edc82b53ac0249ca710ff8fd4fea54)
- Installed    compatible Cython=0.29.9 as mentioned [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux-venvs.html#linux-run-app)

Solved the problem by updating to the latest Cython version (0.29.16 for me):

```
pip install --upgrade Cython
```

Comment: I did that, was .10 and now is .16. Keeps returning the same error...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have cython or something is wrong with cython. Consider installing it with the command mentioned from alexmazurik

Comment: Oh, now I remember I had the same error. But I just deleted my virtual box session and created a new one. It took me some time, but it eventually worked. You could try this